# Record phone calls on android phone?

Tags: java, android

I tried it and use the following code for recording outgoing calls but it does not..

```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
          this.context = context;
          if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)) 
          {
              try
              {
                  phonenbr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                  Log.v("GDHGDHGHDGDHGDHGHDGHDGH", phonenbr);
                  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                  recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                  recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                  recorder.setOutputFile(pathname);
                  recorder.prepare();
                  recorder.start();
                  recordstarted = 1;
                  telManager= (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }


              final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener()
                {
                    @Override
                     public void onCallStateChanged(final int state, final String incomingNumber)
                        {
                            getTelephonyOverview(telManager);
                        }
                };

           telManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}
```

}

```
           public void getTelephonyOverview(final TelephonyManager telManager)
           {
                   int callState = telManager.getCallState();
                   switch (callState)
                   {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    {
                        if (recordstarted==1)
                        {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted =0;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
           }
```

Please provide some good solution for this problem..

Comment: if u can provide catlog of errors, then i might help..

Comment: hi there, I am also in need of recording phone calls. Did you you get a chance to make it working?

Comment: Cool idea, but before you get too far I suggest that you check out your local laws that relate to privacy and recording telephone calls. I know that in the US there are very strict rules as to what can be recorded and notifying the user that they are being recorded.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved with API level 8+. Set your audio source for media recorder as phone uplink, downlink, or both.

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL); //Voice downlink/ Uplink
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AAC );
```

But beware of the law and regulations before doing this.

Comment: I tried this on my Droid X, but I keep getting "stop failed: -1007" RuntimeException from MediaRecorder on recorder.stop(). recorder.start() passes without issue and a non zero sized file is created, but is unplayable.

Comment: Which phones have you tried this on? It looks like a too simple solution to be true... and then they tend to be :)

Answer (score 4):

1. You cannot record phone calls very well in Android, because the in-call audio is not available to SDK applications
2. `ACTION_ANSWER` is [not](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER) a broadcast `Intent`

Comment: Is there any other way to record phone calls ??

Comment: I had a look a while ago, and there was no way of doing it.

Comment: There isn't - you can't even find out who's calling until after the call completes (which is great when the phone crashes mid-call)

Comment: @Kanika No, you can't record phone calls, because you don't have access to the in call audio  stream at the SDK (or even system) level.  (No idea how I accidentally ventured into a months old thread, apologies..)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot record call simply by media recorder. you have to also change the setting of audio manager and put the loud speaker on before starting recording and the audio source will remain same(mic).So try to edit audio manager's setting

---

```
AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService("audio"); 
int i = audiomanager.getRouting(2); 
audiomanager.setMode(2);
audiomanager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true); 
int j = audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(0); 
if(j < 0) 
     j = 1; 
int k = j / 2 + 1; 
audiomanager.setStreamVolume(0, k, 0); 
audiomanager.setRouting(2, 11, 15);
```

Comment: but how to put the loud speaker on ?

Comment: @Kartik You need to add change audio setting permossion in your mainfeast file. Here is my code :     `AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService("audio");        int i = audiomanager.getRouting(2);        audiomanager.setMode(2);
   audiomanager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
      audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
      int j = audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(0);
         if(j < 0)
             j = 1;
         int k = j / 2 + 1; audiomanager.setStreamVolume(0, k, 0);
          audiomanager.setRouting(2, 11, 15);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot record a call from the API. One common workaround is to engage the speakerphone and record from the microphone - on many devices, the microphone will pick up the speaker adequately with this arrangement.

Another workaround is to do the recording on a telephony service somewhere and route calls through it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me to **record outgoing phone calls**,so please check it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android/21331756#21331756)