# record voice when phone incoming call or outgoing call

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Record phone calls on android phone ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370278/record-phone-calls-on-android-phone)

Hi, is this possible record voice call if yes please tell me how?