# VOICE_DOWNLINK doesn't work

Tags: android, call, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to record audio from a phone call, but when I use:

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK
```

the app hasn't errors, but it doesn't work. When I use:

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
```

the application works good, and it can record all the phone call audio, the bad thing here is that it only works with some devices.

Do you know why MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK doens't work?

Comment: if you are trying to record audio from a phone call, have you tried it with `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL`?  
For your question, it is really not possible to tell why `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK` is not working without having a clue of how you are doing it.

Comment: @SyedDany Yes I tried .VOICE_CALL, .CAMCORDER, .COMMUNICATION and also .REMOTE_SUBMIX, but not none of them worked. And I'm trying to analyze the data from a phone call during a phone call.

Comment: Have you tried to alter the 'DeviceAdminPolicy' as it is done in the below given link?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android 
See if this can help you.