# Record incoming phone call Android

Tags: android, recording, phone-call

Is it possible for an Android app to listen and record the conversation of a phone call that is happening and that is handled by the built-in system phone call manager?

I have seen this answer:

[How to record phone calls in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android)

But I am not sure the answer is still valid for my case or if they added other solutions.