# Record incoming audio from call while they are on hold

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-phone-call

Is it possible to record the audio from the incoming end, while you have placed the call on hold on an Android device.

Here is a sequence of events that would lead to the case I am trying to figure out:

1) Call is made/received -> Ongoing Call

2) Call is placed on hold -> Call on Hold

3) From the device that has placed the call on hold, record any audio from the incoming call (I guess you could call this the audio behind the hold?)

Recording calls had been addressed, in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android), but I am not too familiar with the background workings of the in-call actions. Does putting a call on "hold" block all incoming audio?

To summarize: is any audio/discussion from "behind the hold" feasible, and if so how?