# Phone call recording in android 7.0 and higher version

Tags: android, call-recording

I have used this code, working for android 5.1(MotoE and MotoX and 1 more device) and 8.1.0(Nokia 6) But not working for 8.0(One Plus 5) and 7.0(MotoG5).

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    //recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(320000);
                    //recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/AutoCallPicker/PhoneCallRecord/");
                if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                    sampleDir.mkdirs();
                }
                //String file_name = "Record";
                String file_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());//Naming according to date and time
                try {
                    audioFile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr",
                            sampleDir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Set output file .
                recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //String formattedMessage[] = audioFile.getAbsolutePath().split(Commands.SPLIT_BY_SLASH);
                //fileNameRecordedCall = formattedMessage[formattedMessage.length - 1].toString();
                try {
                    //Call prepare before start().
                    recorder.prepare();
                    //Start recording .
                    recorder.start();
                    recordStarted = true;
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

permissions given

```
     <!-- Calling permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<!-- permission to write on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have also used Device Policy Manager and made my device admin as mentioned in accepted answer of below link
[How to record phone calls in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android)

but this thing is not working for any device.Please help what setting I am missing.

Comment: Did you ask for permissions explicitly on android api lvl 23+ (Marshmallow and above)?

Comment: How do you determine that you need to start recording?

Comment: @bko Yes I have asked for permissions explicitly on android api level 23+(Marshmallow and above), actually getting only my voice not able to record incoming voice in higher versions of android.

Comment: @Malcolm I start recording after getting TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK