# how to record call for both side android

Tags: android, call-recording

i tired using MediaRecorder to record call phone 
all setting i am testing it

```
   this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                this.mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
                this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
                this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
                this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
```

but the record only sound from mic

i want to record both side call like android app 
[Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see this call recording [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android) on stack overflow. It'll cover all the things you need to do call recording.