# Call recording in android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to add a call recording feature to my app. The code/help avaiable all over the internet uses MediaRecorder. However, it is not working on the android version greater than 6, especially android 10. Only my voice is recorded, but the incoming voice is not recorded. I have also read that android does not allow call recording after updates. But there are many apps on the play store which record calls (both outgoing and incoming voice). So, there must be some way to do that. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All those answers use MediaRecorder, and for me, it's not working. MediaRecorder records only my voice, not other sides' voice.

Comment: Please see this link : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18887746/14884388